# Using LAG() function to find past value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, window-functions

I've used the Lag Function to find the previous value. However I have run into an issue that requires a more complex query.

Here is my scenario. 
Our table currently keeps month end data for each record. With the exception of the last 95 days. we like to keep daily records fro the last 95 days. This is what I mean by month end and daily records

```
ID      Date       Amount 
123  10/31/2019      52
123  11/31/2019      56
123  12/31/2019      59
123  01/25/2020      32
123  01/26/2020      28  
123      ...         ..   
123  03/12/2020      103
```

Imagine that the ... represent a daily record for id: 123 up until yesterday.

My task worked perfectly for our month end historical data, but i ran into an issue with our daily historical data

what I want is to be able to get the last value from the last day of the previous month for all months.

this is what I currently have for my query

```
Select ID, Date, Amount,LAG(Amount, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY ID
   ORDER BY id,
            Date)
   AS SharePreviousBalance from dbo.shares
where date >= 20191031
```

This is the output I would like to have, but my current query does not work the way i want it to work:

```
ID      Date       Amount  SharePreviousBalance
123  10/31/2019      52         0
123  11/31/2019      56         52
123  12/31/2019      59         56
123   ...            ..         ..
123  01/25/2020      32         0
123  01/26/2020      28         0
123  01/27/2020      28         0
123      ...         ..         ..
123  01/31/2020      28         59
123     ...          ..         ..
123  02/15/2020      28         0
123      ...         ..         ..
123  02/29/2020      25         28
123      ...         ..         ..
123  03/05/2020      29         0
123      ...         ..         ..
123  03/10/2020      30         0
123      ...         ..         ..
123  03/12/2020      103        25
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Aside: Once you `partition by Id` there shouldn't be much benefit to `order by Id`, just `order by [Date]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little conditional logic, you can still do this with `lag()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when date = eomonth(date) then 
        coalesce(
            lag(amount) over(
                partition by id, case when date = eomonth(date) then 1 else 0 end
                order by date
            ),
            0
        )
    end SharePreviousBalance
from mytable t
```

The idea is to build a partition for "end-of-month" rows (ie rows whose `date` is the last day of a month). Within that partition, an end-of-month row can access the previous end of month with `lag()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31f331b4c62118edbb48897ed0f80801)** - I added a few rows to your sample data:

```
 ID | Date       | Amount | SharePreviousBalance
--: | :--------- | -----: | -------------------:
123 | 2019-10-31 |     52 |                    0
123 | 2019-11-30 |     56 |                   52
123 | 2019-12-31 |     59 |                   56
123 | 2020-01-20 |     28 |                 null
123 | 2020-01-25 |     32 |                 null
123 | 2020-01-26 |     28 |                 null
123 | 2020-01-31 |     28 |                   59
123 | 2020-02-12 |    103 |                 null
123 | 2020-02-28 |    103 |                 null
123 | 2020-02-29 |    103 |                   28
```

---

If you also want to show the value of the previous end of month for the current date, then add that row to the "end-of-month" partition:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when date in (eomonth(date), cast(getdate() as date)) then 
        coalesce(
            lag(amount) over(
                partition by 
                    id, 
                    case when date in (eomonth(date), cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end
                order by date
            ),
            0
        )
    end SharePreviousBalance
from mytable t
order by id, date
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, This works perfectly! The only other thing that I was hoping to get was a previous month end value to be inserted on the current day of the month if it has not reached the month end.... I know!! it gets complicated!

Comment: For example: todays date would have amount of 103, which is the value from 2020-02-29.

Comment: @WWaldo: ah, my bad, that was showing in your question though. I updated my answer with a modified query.